# Установка пакета npm и взаимодействие с ним [nodejs, npm]

Tags: npm, node-modules

cовсем не давно решил поставить [buefy](https://github.com/rafaelpimpa/buefy), хватило только на команду `npm install buefy`, дальше, появилась папка node_modules... и как взаимодействовать с её компонентами с index.html, не понятно.

Разъясните пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен. [[От ссылок на мануалы не отказываюсь}

Comment: https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как использовать написано на странице ссылку на которую вы дали [Buefy](https://github.com/rafaelpimpa/buefy).

Buefy это библиотека компонентов для фреймворка [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/). Документация по Vue.js на русском язык доступна [тут](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/). После установки модулей вы должны подключить Buefy во Vue.js. Как это сделать описано в документации. Вот пример (из документации):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import 'buefy/lib/buefy.css'

Vue.use(Buefy)
```

Comment: поместил код в <script> получаю `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: ваш браузер не поддерживает ECMAScript 2015 и вам надо использовать Babel.